# Glass Mapper Umbraco - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: umbraco, castle-windsor, umbraco7, glass-mapper

I've recently followed [this post](http://bluetubeinc.com/blog/2014/6/glass-mapper-and-umbraco-7) on how to set up Umbraco and Glass Mapper. All of my code is set up the same as the example. However I keep on getting an error when I create a controller.

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Do I have to set something up in Castle Windsor?

Comment: That exception usually means you're still missing some dependency registrations. Have you traced every dependency to a registration? It can be something as silly as missing a single registration somewhere in the dependency chain.

Comment: We recently attempted to go down the path of glassmapper with Umbraco, but found the support for 7.3+ to be lacking. We ended up going with Umbraco's Ditto and have had a much easier time of it.

Comment: I managed to make this work. I agree with you, however. It seems like the support for Glass Mapper in Umbraco is lacking. So I might end up using another mapper.